# 403 forbidden Error oftenly may be due to some htacess rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I am facing a severe issue in one of my project.
On live website, i am getting a 403 error for some images as well as for html pages.
After setting up the project on local machine, found it was due to following:-

1. Some wrong rules of htaccess (after correction, moved them to vhost files & now htaccess is empty)
2. Also found some deprecated functions of php like mysql_connect() , ereg() & etc. 
   I had fixed them all & make it working fine on local, but when applied all the changes to live server, it still shows the 403 error sometimes which vanish on page refresh.

Here is the configuration in my vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.net
ServerAlias www.domain.net
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/live-working-directory"
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "/var/www/html/live-working-directory">
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !redir
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]

RewriteMap maps "prg:/var/www/html/live-working-directory/rewrite"  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z])-([0-9]+).html$
RewriteRule ^/([a-z])-([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?
cmd=fh,alpha&alpha=$1&page=$2 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/privacy-policy.html$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?cmd=fh,article&art_id=4 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/terms-of-use.html$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?cmd=fh,article&art_id=5 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about-us.html$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?cmd=fh,article&art_id=6 [L]
#Rules for two new custome pages


RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${maps:$1|$1} [QSA,L]



ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain__access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: The question is why i am getting 403 on some internal pages of site. Is anything wrong with the vhost configuration.

Comment: Can you provide an exact URL that results in 403? Also, there is a RewriteMap `prg:/var/www/html/live-working-directory/rewrite` that we don't know what is doing.

Comment: Also: do you have access to apache .conf files and error log?

Comment: The rules i have mentioned in my question is apache conf file only and i have checked the error log it says - Access denied by server configuration.
The exact setup with same configuration on local machine  works fine.

Comment: And regarding RewriteMap maps "prg:/var/www/html/live-working-directory/rewrite"
this file contains database connectivity to fetch images

Comment: Does it help if you change `Allow from 127.0.0.1` to `Allow from all`?

Comment: No . I have already tried this.